# Getting "Undefined" Halfway Through Iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordnet

I have a Node.js app that I want to pull a tweet, tokenize the text, and then use WordNet to identify the part of speech for each word. Currently, I'm getting multiple results for each word. Using something like `results[0].pos` returns a few results then somehow gives me a "can't get property of undefined" error. Sometimes it happens after one result, sometimes after two or three. Here's the function in question:

```
stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
    var words = tokenizer.tokenize(tweet.text);
    words.forEach(function(word) {
        wordnet.lookup(word, function(results) {
            console.log(results[0].pos);
                console.log("");
            });
        });
    });
```

Any ideas on how to get 1 result for each word and only 1 pos for each result without getting "Undefined"?

Comment: It sounds like you have some words that aren't in WordNet. You'll want to check whether the result set is empty before trying to access its members.

Comment: @Chuck Theoretically I would only want the first result, which does exist because I usually get a few valid results before I get an undefined one. To clarify: I get a couple of results _per word_ and some of those return normal values and others are undefined seemingly without pattern.

Comment: Unless I am completely misreading, that isn't what's happening in the code you've shown. It may be returning more than one result per word, but you're only accessing the first result (`results[0]`). But for some words, there isn't even a first result, so `results[0]` gives `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to mention in OP I guess. Each `results` set also includes several definitions for the word, all of which include their own pos. So `results[0].pos` should return: `v a a v n` and so on. Its currently returning `v a` then an undefined error.